# request parameter in beforeSave() doesn't contain any stored values sent from android app

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is my android code :

```
ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("likes");
            ParseObject parseuser=ParseObject.createWithoutData(ParseUser.class,post.getPosAuthorObjectId());
            ParseObject parsepost=ParseObject.createWithoutData("posts",post.getObjectId());
            parsepost.put("postAuthor",parseuser);
            parseObject.put("ownerId", ParseObject.createWithoutData(ParseUser.class, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()));
            parseObject.put("postId",parsepost);
            parseObject.saveInBackground
```

I am trying to send some data regarding the user's id along with the post object so as to save the post object int the "likes" class and do changes in the post owner's attributes using masterkey without fetching the id of the post owner in a separate query as it is already stored in my android code .In my experimental beforeSave():

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("likes",function(request,response){
var posts = Parse.Object.extend("posts");
var post=new posts();
var post=request.object.get("postId");
var user=Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
var user=new Parse.User();
var  id =post.object.get("postAuthor").id;
if(id!=null){
    response.success();
}
else{
    response.error("The id is null");
}
});
```

Basically I am trying to retrieve the user id saved in the postobject and sent to the request parameter .But the output of my experiment is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extending the Parse.Object for the user class and setting a new user using the same variable name. You can just get rid of the first var user line completely, since new Parse.User() works by default without any extending.

Anyway, try just `console.log( request.object );` to see what you're actually passing in.

Comment: Thank you.I did what you said and found out that the parseuser put in the parsepost object was not getting received at the request parameter in the cloud code .So is there any other way to achieve the task that tried in the android code  since the createwithoutdata() method doesnot  let me put attributes in it after creation.Please help.Thank you.